# A for loop somehow overrides an entire array, even though I can see no reason for that

Tags: c#

So, been looking at this code for a good while now, and I am lost. 
The point is to run a for loop that adds classes to an array, and then for each class runs through an array of points inside of that class, and add variations to it.

This then shows as a bunch of dots on a form, which are supposed to move independently of each other, but now follows each other completely.
It does not matter how much variation there is or anything, it's just 99 dots with the exact same acceleration, velocity, and location, and path.

The code is here, the method isn't touched by any other code, and the problem arises before it returns.

```
    //Point of the method is to put variations of Baby into an array, and return that array
        Dot.Class[] MutateAndListBaby(Dot.Class Baby)
        {
            //Making the empty array
            Dot.Class[] BabyList = new Dot.Class[dots.Length];

            //For loop that goes through through the whole array
            for (int i = 1; i < BabyList.Length; i++)
            {
                //For each itteration the for loop adds the class reference to the index, then puts the standard directions into that reference, and then sets a value preventing it from being changed in another code
                BabyList[i] = new Dot.Class();
                BabyList[i].Directions = Baby.Directions;
                BabyList[i].StartupComplete = true;

                //The zero index variation when made like this, allows it to not be overriden, which would lead one to believe that how the directions are copied is he problem
                //But it shouldn't be, BabyList[i].Directions = Baby.Directions; should be fire and forget, it should just add the Directions to the array and then leave it


                BabyList[0] = new Dot.Class();
                BabyList[0].Directions = new PointF[100];
                for (int b = 0; b < BabyList[0].Directions.Length; b++)
                {
                    BabyList[0].Directions[b] = new Point (5, 10);
                }

                BabyList[0].StartupComplete = true;

                //The for loop that shuld add variation, but it seems like it somehow overrides it self, somehow
                for (int b = 0; b < BabyList[i].Directions.Length; b++)
                {

                    if (rand.Next(0, 101) >= 100)
                    {


                            int rando = rand.Next(-50, 51);
                            float mod = (float)rando / 50;
                            float x = BabyList[i].Directions[b].X;

                            x = x + mod;

                            BabyList[i].Directions[b].X = rand.Next(-5, 6);



                    }

                    if (rand.Next(0, 101) >= 100)
                    {
                        int rando = rand.Next(-50, 51);
                        float mod = (float)rando / 50;
                        float y = BabyList[i].Directions[b].Y;

                        y = y * mod;

                        BabyList[i].Directions[b].Y = rand.Next(-5, 6);

                    }




                }

                //Now one would assume this would create a unique dot that would move 100% independently right? Since it's at the end of the for loop, so nothin should change it
                // Nope, somehow it makes every other dot copy its directions...

                if (i == 5)
                {

                    for (int b = 0; b < BabyList[5].Directions.Length; b++)
                    {
                        BabyList[5].Directions[b] = new PointF(-5f, -5f);
                    }

                }

            }


            return BabyList;

        }

    }
}
```

With the code there, what I get is the 0 index dot going its own way, while the other 99 dots for some reason follow the 5th index's Directions, even though they should get their own variations later on in the code.

Any help would be much appreciated, it probarbly something obvious, but trust me, been looking at this thing for quite a while, can't see anything.

Comment: `(rand.Next(0, 101) >= 100`  You probably wanted `<=`

Comment: @Mars `(rand.Next(0, 101) <= 100` means `always`

Comment: Anyway, `(rand.Next(0, 101) >= 100` is the same as `(rand.Next(0, 101) == 100`, or `(rand.Next(0, 101) == 0` or `(rand.Next(0, 101) == 42`

Comment: Good catch! It still doesn't change the fact that OP probably wanted to do it 99 times out of 100, not 1 time though

Comment: I actually did want to do it 1 out of 100 times, it's a evolution program, so needed only small variations, but appreciate the help anyways

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, this might be the issue:

```
BabyList[i].Directions = Baby.Directions;
```

Directions is of type array of PointF - a reference. The line above does not copy the array. Is that what you assume? If I'm not misreading the code you're presenting, you're creating one Dot.Class with its own array of PointF at index 0 and fill the rest of your Dot.Class array with instances that *share one single array*.

Comment: Probably not the case, but Baby.Directions could have a getter that returns a copy to an array

Comment: Fair enough. Oooor it's not even a property, it's a field. Without code we've got no way to tell. It _would_ explain why they claim that changes are overwritten though

Comment: Oooh, yeah, I did assume it simply copied the Directions over, I can totally understand the problems I have been suffering now. Well, gotta go google how to copy arrays! Thanks for the help :) You have made a very tired person, quite happy

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to change your if conditions:

```
(rand.Next(0, 101) >= 100
```

to

```
(rand.Next(0, 100) < 99
```

This will run an average of 99 times out of 100, whereas your current condition runs 1 out of 101 times (on average)

---

Oh, and Benjamin Podszun's answer about assigning the same array (not a copy of the same array) to Directions apply as well!
(Assuming that Directions isn't a getter that you created to return a copy of an array instead of a reference!)

Comment: Nope, len(range(0, 101)) (sorry, python!) will be 101 :)

Comment: shi~, I forget about 0, sorry :)

Answer (score 0):

Directions is array, which is a reference type. When you're making assigment  of a variable of this type

```
BabyList[i].Directions = Baby.Directions;
```

no new instance is created and reference us just being copied into new variable which still references original instance. Essentially in your loop only very first item gets a new instance of  Directions as it's explicitly constructed. The rest share the instance which comes as a member of  parameter passed to the method.